# Approximation of module gsl or Asymptote own calculation is the best?

Tags: asymptote, calculations, decimal-number

Example:

```
import graph;
import gsl;
size(12cm,false);
defaultpen(linewidth(.7bp));
real f(real x){return x^2;}
real g(real x){return 2^x;}

draw(graph(f,-1.5,5),red);
draw(graph(g,-1.5,5),blue);

draw(Label("$x$",EndPoint,align=S),(-2,0)--(5,0),Arrow(TeXHead));
draw(Label("$y$",EndPoint,align=W),(0,-3)--(0,g(5)),Arrow(TeXHead));

real margin=.1;
for (int i: new int[]{2,4}){
draw(Label("$"+(string) i+"$",Relative(0)),(i,0)-(0,margin)--(i,0)+(0,margin));
draw(Label("$"+(string) g(i)+"$",Relative(0)),(0,g(i))-(margin,0)--(0,g(i))+(margin,0));
draw((i,0)--(i,g(i))--(0,g(i)),linetype(new real[]{5,5}));
}

pair z[]=intersectionpoints(graph(f,-1.5,5),graph(g,-1.5,5));
arrow(Label(format("$z[0].x=%.50f$",z[0].x)),z[0],dir=dir(-90));
real Lam=-2*Wm1(log(2)/2)/log(2);
arrow(Label(format("$Lambert W=%.50f$",Lam)),z[0],dir=dir(90),.5cm);
dot(z);
label("$0$",0,dir(-135));
```

[image]

Support:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%3D2%5Ex
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345581/c-printf-a-float-value

Question:

1. Why Asymptote get two different results and what is the best approximation?
2. Although `%.50f` but only `42` decimal digits after the comma as my output!! Do you have a exact output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would trust the `gsl` result here. You obtain the Asymptote result by intersecting two paths that represent the graphs of functions. However, these paths are only *approximately* the graphs of functions; they are hoped to be accurate up to human vision, but not for 50 digits. If you want to make the path-intersection result more accurate, you can try something like

```
pair z[]=intersectionpoints(graph(f,-1.5,5, n=200, Hermite),graph(g,-1.5,5, n=200, Hermite));
```

and keep increasing `n` for more accurate results (at the cost of significantly more computation time). But the `intersectionpoints` function uses "machine precision" at best; assuming that means 64-bit floats, you're never, ever going to get more than 16 significant digits in the base-10 representation via the Asymptote method.

Concerning the second question: the `real` type is a 64-bit float under the hood, which means in your decimal printout, everything after the first 16 digits or so is complete garbage. I'm not sure why you get 40 digits; I would guess this is an exact representation of the base-2 float that is the "true" result, but that can't be true because if it were the final digit would be 5, not 4.